# type char exceed 10485760 limit error still showing after I change the limit to something less than MAX

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a django app, I'm migrating it's database from sqlite3 to postgres, i get the following error line since i got a field in one of the models set to 500000000 so i changed it to 10485750 and ran:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app
python manage.py sqlmigrate app 0001
python manage.py migrate
```

but still got the following error

```
django.db.utils.DataError: length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760 LINE 1: ...ber" TYPE varchar(500000000) USING ........
```

how can I make it feel the change I made?

Model:

```
class PartyDetails(models.Model):
model_number=models.CharField(max_length=270)
item_instance_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
contract_model_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
item_group = models.CharField(max_length=250 )
tla_serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True )
product_tla_flag = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True )
location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
install_base_status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
cust_number = models.TextField() 
cust_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
contract_number = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True )
contract_subline_status = models.CharField(max_length=250 )
contract_subline_start_date = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True )
contract_subline_end_date = models.CharField( max_length=250,null=True)
end_life_date = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True )
nested_level = models.IntegerField(null=True)
primary_contract_flag = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True,null=True )


def get_absolute_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
    #return reverse('party-details',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
    return reverse('index')


def __str__(self):
    return "item_instance_number =" + str(self.item_instance_number)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what field type you using? In Django for big texts have models.TextField() class https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField

Are you generate new migration? I recomend clear migrations for this app and generate new, because model is valid

Comment: I'm using CharField, however i changed it to TextField now and it's till giving me the same error

Comment: Edited question, the problem is with the cust_number field